# Работа Expander в WPF

Tags: wpf

В окне имеется DataGrid productsDataGrid, занимающий всю высоту окна.
Под ним имеется элемент Expander с выставленным свойством ExpandDirection="Up", в котором находится ещё  один DataGrid historyDataGrid.
При запуске программы Expander находится в свёрнутом состоянии, а при нажатии на его кнопку поверх productsDataGrid открывается historyDataGrid и занимает нижнюю половину высоты окна.
Проблема в том, что половина строк (начиная снизу) в productsDataGrid недоступна для нажатия мышью даже при свёрнутом Expander'е.[image: Скриншот окна]
Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Можно дополнительно устанавливать Expander'у свойство Visibility перед открытием и после сворачивания.